# creating combined pictures using opencv inrange

Tags: opencv

create a combined picture in opencv

Hi, I have question which is probably related to the "inrange" function.

I want to show  the picture in the following way:
if(picture in range, ) show picture A, else show picture B.

In another word: 
If(color is red) show pixels source picture, else { show pixel from another picture. }

Any suggestions?

the combined picture from A &B

No way.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input images?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can achieve what you requested in your question using the *inrange* function. I am not sure which environment you are working on, so i wrote in c++ as an example. Yon can easily convert it to python if you understand the code below. It is really a simple problem if you understand the [*inrange* function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html).

```
cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("img1.jpg");
cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("img2.jpg");

cv::Scalar lowerBound(10,1,0);
cv::Scalar upperBound(100,200,255);
cv::inrange(img1,lowerBound, upperBound,img2);

cv::imshow("result", img2);
```